# JMM and happens-before

Tags: java

i have a question about JMM. I've known what "happen-before" is, but i don't understand one thing. There is a code:

```
private static int x = 0;
private static volatile boolean flag = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    new Thread(() -> {
        x = 10;
        while (!flag) ;
        System.out.println(x);
    }).start();

    x = 5;
    flag = true;
}
```

what a value does have to be in "X" and is there a rule to determine it?
Maybe in that case is there some order which threads put some value in X by?

Answer (score 0):

Lets first simplify the program a bit by commenting out x=10.

```
private static int x = 0;
private static volatile boolean flag = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    new Thread(() -> {
        //x = 10;
        while (!flag) ;
        System.out.println(x);
    }).start();

    x = 5;
    flag = true;
}
```

In this example 5 will be printed. Why?

```
x=5
|
[program order rule]
|
flag=true
|
[volatile variable rule]
|
tmp1=flag
|
[program order rule]
| 
tmp2=x
```

Because happens before rules also are transitive, there is a happens before relation between x=5 and tmp2=x.

If the x=10 is uncommented, then 10 and 5 are the allowed outcomes.

Comment: Hm. I don't think your final conclusion is correct: "*If the x=10 is uncommented, then 10 and 5 are the allowed outcomes.*" The write-operation to a volatile field *happens-before* the read-operation of that value for another thread. That implies that the thread in this example cannot see `flag == true` without also seeing `x == 5`. So the program will always print `5`. Note that a volatile read affects *all* fields, not only the volatile field itself.